# Vertically align a button to middle without fixing height to present both for mobile and desktop view

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, vertical-alignment

I'm using bootstrap snipplet from bootsnipp on http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/blog-posts-with-picture to create list with rows. 
What I'm tring is to vertical align the red button to middle. I could not find any way to align it fluidly(when the height is 100%) so I've fixed the height to 10em. This time it works work desktop view but for mobile view it creates a gap on the upside and downside of the red button.
Could you help me to align it vertically middle for desktop and mobile view without creating gaps for the mobile view?

[image: Mobile View]
[image: Desktop View]
Here is my html code in HAML. I don't use any specific css, just the bootstrap.

```
.row
  .span8
    .row
      .span8
        %h4
          %strong
            %a{:href => "#"} {{officialname}}
    .row
      .span2
        %a.thumbnail{:href => "#"}
          %img{:src => "{{provider_image}}",id: "provideredit" , alt: ""}
          /%img{alt: "", src: "{{provider_image}}", height: "135", width: "135"}/
      .span6
        .tabbable
        %ul.nav.nav-tabs{:style => "margin-bottom: 10px"}
          %li.active
            %a{"data-toggle" => "tab", :href => "#pane1_{{id}}"} Hakkında
          %li
            %a{"data-toggle" => "tab", :href => "#pane2_{{id}}"} Referansları
          %li
            %a{"data-toggle" => "tab", :href => "#pane3_{{id}}"} Sertifikaları
          %li
            %a{"data-toggle" => "tab", :href => "#pane4_{{id}}"} Fotoğrafları
        .tab-content{:style => "margin-bottom: 10px"}
          #pane1.tab-pane.active{:id => "{{id}}"}
            {{business_description}}
          #pane2.tab-pane{:id => "{{id}}"} 
            {{#each references}}
            %ul.unstyled.comments.list-hover.list-striped
              %li
                .avatar1.pull-left
                  /%img{:alt => "Avatar", :height => "23", :src => "#", :width => "23"}/                                   
                .body
                  .name
                    %a.text-contrast{:href => "#"}  {{referencer}} | {{category}}                     
                    %a1.btn1.btn1-link.ok.has-tooltip.pull-right 
                      Makul Fiyat
                      {{#ifCond pricerating "1"}}
                      %i.icon-thumbs-up
                      {{else}}
                      %i.icon-thumbs-down
                      {{/ifCond}}                      
                    %a1.btn1.btn1-link.remove.has-tooltip.pull-right 
                      Hizmet Kalitesi
                      {{#ifCond servicerating "1"}}
                      %i.icon-thumbs-up
                      {{else}}
                      %i.icon-thumbs-down
                      {{/ifCond}}      
                  %p
                  .text {{body}}
                .text-right
                  %small.date.muted
                    %i.icon-time
                    %span.timeago.fade.has-tooltip.in{"data-original-title" => "August 28, 2013 - 11:08", "data-placement" => "top", :title => ""} 17 days ago                    
            {{/each}} 
          #pane3.tab-pane{:id => "{{_id}}"}
            .qualification-gallery
              %a{ href: "{{certificate_image1.url}}"}
                %img{alt: "", src: "{{certificate_image1.thumb.url}}", height: "135", width: "135"}/
              %a{ href: "{{certificate_image2.url}}"}
                %img{alt: "", src: "{{certificate_image2.thumb.url}}", height: "135", width: "135"}/
              %a{ href: "{{licence_image1.url}}"}
                %img{alt: "", src: "{{licence_image1.thumb.url}}", height: "135", width: "135"}/
              %a{ href: "{{licence_image2.url}}"}
                %img{alt: "", src: "{{licence_image2.thumb.url}}", height: "135", width: "135"}/
          #pane4.tab-pane{:id => "{{_id}}"}
            .image-gallery
              %a{ href: "{{provider_image.url}}"}
                %img{alt: "", src: "{{provider_image.thumb.url}}", height: "135", width: "135"}/
              %a{ href: "{{provider_image1.url}}"}
                %img{alt: "", src: "{{provider_image1.thumb.url}}", height: "135", width: "135"}/
              %a{ href: "{{provider_image2.url}}"}
                %img{alt: "", src: "{{provider_image2.thumb.url}}", height: "135", width: "135"}/
              %a{ href: "{{provider_image3.url}}"}
                %img{alt: "", src: "{{provider_image3.thumb.url}}", height: "135", width: "135"}/      
    .row
      .span8
        %p
        %p
          %i.icon-certificate
          %a{:href => "#"} {{workdonecount}} Hizmet Vermiş
          |
          %i.icon-credit
          %a{:href => "#"} {{pricescore}} Fiyat Puanı
          |
          %i.icon-thumbs-up
          %a{:href => "#"} {{servicescore}} Hizmet Puanı
          |
          %i.icon-map-marker
          %input{:id=>"lat1_{{id}}", type: "hidden",value: "{{lat}}" }/
          %input{:id=>"lat2_{{id}}", type: "hidden",value: "{{itinerarylat}}" }/
          %input{:id=>"lon1_{{id}}", type: "hidden",value: "{{lng}}" }/
          %input{:id=>"lon2_{{id}}", type: "hidden",value: "{{itinerarylon}}" }/
          %output{:id=>"result-distance_{{id}}"}        
          |
          %i.icon-share
          %a{:href => "#"} 3 Arkadaşın Hizmet Almış
          |
          %i.icon-check
          %a{:href => "#"} Hizmetkutusu Onaylı
  .span3
    .row{style: "height: 10em; display: table-cell; vertical-align:middle;"}
      %input.style3{:id=>"givequote", :type => "checkbox" , data: { id: "{{id}}" } }/
      %input#provider_id{:name => "provider_id", :type => "hidden", :value =>  "{{id}}" }/

%hr/
:javascript

  $(document).ready(function() { 
    var p1 = new LatLon(Geo.parseDMS($('#lat1_{{id}}').val()), Geo.parseDMS($('#lon1_{{id}}').val()));
    var p2 = new LatLon(Geo.parseDMS($('#lat2_{{id}}').val()), Geo.parseDMS($('#lon2_{{id}}').val()));
    $('#result-distance_{{id}}').html(p1.distanceTo(p2)+' km');

    $('input[type="checkbox"].style3').checkbox({
      buttonStyle: 'btn-danger',
        buttonStyleChecked: 'btn-success',
      checkedClass: 'icon-check' ,
        uncheckedClass: 'icon-check-empty'
    }); 
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best solution is to use media queries to target the mobile browser size to have height be equal to your button height. 
For example :

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .teklif {
    height: 40px;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you max. I've sorted it out

Answer (score 0):

Thank You Max. Regards to your answer I've sorted it out by this css.

Haml:

```
 .span3
    .row{id: "xx2"}
      %input.style3{:id=>"givequote", :type => "checkbox" , data: { id: "{{id}}" } }/
      %input#provider_id{:name => "provider_id", :type => "hidden", :value =>  "{{id}}" }/

:css
  /* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
  @media only screen 
  and (min-device-width : 320px) 
  and (max-device-width : 480px) {
    #xx2 {
      display: table-cell;  
      vertical-align: middle;  
      height: 40px; important !
    }
  }

  /* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */
  @media only screen 
  and (min-width : 321px) {
    #xx2 {
      display: table-cell;  
      vertical-align: middle;  
      height: 40px; important !
    }
  }

  /* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
  @media only screen 
  and (max-width : 320px) {
    #xx2 {
      display: table-cell;  
      vertical-align: middle;  
      height: 40px; important !
    }
  }

  /* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
  @media only screen 
  and (min-device-width : 768px) 
  and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
    /* Styles */
  }

  /* iPads (landscape) ----------- */
  @media only screen 
  and (min-device-width : 768px) 
  and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
  and (orientation : landscape) {
    #xx2 {
      display: table-cell;  
      vertical-align: middle;  
      height: 200px; important !
    }
  }

  /* iPads (portrait) ----------- */
  @media only screen 
  and (min-device-width : 768px) 
  and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
  and (orientation : portrait) {
    #xx2 {
      display: table-cell;  
      vertical-align: middle;  
      height: 200px; important !
    }
  }

  /* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
  @media only screen 
  and (min-width : 1224px) {
    #xx2 {
      display: table-cell;  
      vertical-align: middle;  
      height: 200px; important !
    }
  }

  /* Large screens ----------- */
  @media only screen 
  and (min-width : 1824px) {
    #xx2 {
      display: table-cell;  
      vertical-align: middle;  
      height: 200px; important !
    }
  }

  /* iPhone 4 ----------- */
  @media
  only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5),
  only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5) {
    #xx2 {
      display: table-cell;  
      vertical-align: middle;  
      height: 200px; important !
    }
  }

  /* iPhone 5 -------To-DO---- */
  @media
  only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.7),
  only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.7) {
    #xx2 {
      display: table-cell;  
      vertical-align: middle;  
      height: 200px; important !
    }
  }
```